# Using 'xfrac' with 'mathrsfs'

Tags: fonts, warnings, fontsize, xfrac

I'm attempting to move from the `nicefrac` package to `xfrac`. The following source compiles, but with a warning:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
  $\sfrac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'U/rsfs/m/n' in size <3.49998> not available`

It appears as though `xfrac` attempts to load *all* current math alphabets in its typeset size, even if they are not used in the fraction. Is there a variant of `rsfs` that supports fractional sizes? Or a way to prevent `xfrac` from loading it unless it is needed?

Basically, I'd like to suppress this warning unless LaTeX is actually typesetting a glyph from `rsfs` at a fractional size. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed font sizes of rsfs font in NFSS scheme is declared in `ursfs.fd`. It contains

```
\ProvidesFile{ursfs.fd}[1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)]
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <5> <6> rsfs5
   <7> rsfs7
   <8> <9> <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> rsfs10
}{}
```

Now you can modify it for continuous font sizes. You can just put the code in preamble:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6> rsfs5
   <6-8> rsfs7
   <8-> rsfs10
}{}
\begin{document}
  $\sfrac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hah, you barely beat me to it! I just discovered this by digging into `fix-cm`'s source. I was, however, missing the `\skewchar\font127`. Is there any reason _not_ to define this in terms of continuous font sizes? Or is this just something that wasn't possible long ago and has simply propagated through today?

Comment: Now we are using Type1 fonts. They are scalable vector font. However, there are only bitmap fonts produced by MetaFont years ago, scaling is not preferred for performance reason.