# poster presentation math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath, beamerposter, posters

I'm using this template for a poster presentation. In the main result block/alertblock, the math symbols do not appear in the desired size. Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{beamerposter} 
\usetheme{confposter} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale}
\title{.} 
\author{.} 
\institute{.} 


\begin{document} 

\begin{frame} 
$$\mathcal{D}$$
\[ \sum x \] 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

**\mathscr{}** not the same size as the other symbols:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exscale}


\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} 

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} 
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} 
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} 


\usepackage{booktabs} 

\title{Hello} 

\author{} 

\institute{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] 

\begin{columns}[t] 

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} 

\begin{column}{.29\textwidth}

\begin{alertblock}{Abstract}

\end{alertblock}


\begin{block}{Introduction}


\end{block}

\begin{block}{Background material}
\begin{itemize}
\item Note
\[
(\mathscr{A}_r f  )(x)=100 x. 
\]

\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{column} % End of the first column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{.38\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Materials}





\end{block}








\end{column} % End of the second column

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{.29\textwidth}

\begin{block}{Conclusion}


\end{block}


\begin{block}{Additional Information}


\end{block}







\end{column} 

\end{columns} 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: While your example does show the problem, most of it isn't needed. (You're asking about `\sum`, why all the text and images etc?) In fact, all you need is `\documentclass{beamer} \usepackage{beamerposter} \usetheme{confposter} \title{.} \author{.} \institute{.} \begin{document} \begin{frame}  \[ \sum x \] \end{frame}  \end{document}`, and removing `confposter` also removes the problem. (That is why we ask for [*minimal* examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it makes it a lot clearer where the problem actually is.)

Comment: `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`, at least the version I have, does `\RequirePackage{lmodern}`, so it's likely the same problem I referred to in your previous question (now deleted?), and you can try the same fix, as mentioned in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119660/ `\usepackage{exscale}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you very much. I tried \usepackage{excale} and within the block, the desired size appeared. Still, the \mathscr{} and \mathcal{} symbols don't appear in the normal size.

Comment: OK, then can you edit your example to remove all the unnecessary bits (cf. my first comment), and also add in a couple of symbols with `\mathcal`/`\mathscr`?  (Now that you mention it I remember you saying something about that in your previous question, but there is no mention of them in this question, and they do not appear in the code.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just did.

Comment: You should not use `$$..$$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503

Comment: This is what I get from your MWE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quGbq.png Which size do you want to change?

Comment: @samcarter, thank you. In fact I'm using \begin{equation}.... \end{equation} and those symbols I'm using within a block. If I use those particular symbols with a regular lower case letter, the size of the former is smaller than the letter. That's the issue.

Comment: @Fib1123 Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem?

Comment: @samcarter, I just did. Please have a look at equation under Background materials. i put my whole preamble, so not to miss any information.

Comment: @Fib1123 Can you add a link to the version of `confposter` you are using? With the one I found on the internet I cannot compile you MWE because of "no line here to end" errors.

Comment: @samcarter, here's the link of the template I'm working on.
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/landscape-beamer-poster-template/vjpmsxxdvtqk#.WqWiOmrwaYm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Using 'xfrac' with 'mathrsfs'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/using-xfrac-with-mathrsfs)

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter} 

\title{.} 
\author{.} 
\institute{.} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6> rsfs5
   <6-8> rsfs7
   <8-> rsfs10
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] 

\[
A\mathscr{A}
\]

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]